# Best categories and filters for car part shop

Tags: woocommerce

I'm trying to set up a WooCommerce shop for automotive parts. I can't find the best way to filter and categorize the parts, between the type of parts (e.g. light, thermal, motor...) , and the vehicle (brand, model, year) and even the model different versions.
The best way to display this for me would be (like a lot of part shops) a button in the menu for selecting the type of parts, or to choose a brand, a filter in the side menu to filter by brand, then by car, and then that display the car and let me select the type of part on the up, then the part I want...
I started by putting categories for the brand, subcategories for the model, and again categories for the type of part.
How can I display on the side menus the dropdown for brand and model, and then add filters for the type of parts ? This looks like more a filter than a category so how do I add this filter on my CSV import ?